# Default ID in SQL xml

Tags: sql, xml

I am using the `sp_xml_preparedocument` feature of SQL to convert an XML string into a temp table like so:

```
create table #ExportTemplate
(
      ExportTemplateId      uniqueidentifier not null default newid()
    , ExportTypeId          uniqueidentifier not null
    , TemplateDesc          varchar(100) not null
    , Active                bit not null 
    , DateAdded             datetime not null 
    , DateModified          datetime not null 
)

-- If Data is coming in by XML then merge changes into the table
if len(isnull(@XMLString,'')) > 0
begin
    print '*** Merging XML Changes'

    declare     @XMLTable xml
              , @idoc int
              , @Cnt int

    --Load XML
    begin
        set @XMLTable = @XmlString; --Convert string to xml

        exec sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @XMLTable     

        -- insert into #ExportTemplate
        select
                isnull(cast(et.ExportTemplateId as uniqueidentifier), newid()) as ExportTemplateId, 
                cast(et.ExportTypeId as uniqueidentifier) as ExportTypeId,
                et.TemplateDesc,
                et.Active,
                getdate() as DateAdded,
                getdate() as DateModified  
        from    openxml(@idoc,'/ArrayOfTemplate/Template', 2) 
        with (
            ExportTemplateId    uniqueidentifier    'ExportTemplateId',
            ExportTypeId        uniqueidentifier    'ExportTypeId',
            TemplateDesc        varchar(100)        'TemplateDesc',
            Active              bit                 'Active'
        ) et


        set @Cnt = @@rowcount;
        print '*** ' + convert(varchar,@Cnt) + ' rows were retrieved from the XML Table';

        exec sp_xml_removedocument @idoc
    end

    select * from #ExportTemplate
end
```

The XML that I am passing into this function looks like this:

```
<ArrayOfTemplate xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Template>
        <ExportTemplateId>7f0db0ed-d215-4a25-a38a-0305dddc56b3</ExportTemplateId>
        <ExportTypeId>408b6a56-3b7c-41d8-902a-a20f5b2df170</ExportTypeId>
        <TemplateDesc>Census Standard HR</TemplateDesc>
        <Active>false</Active>
        <DataElements />
    </Template>
    <Template>
        <ExportTemplateId>13691df1-9b4c-4b94-b106-41494fe172aa</ExportTemplateId>
        <ExportTypeId>94fb5330-9bd8-4622-8c26-dd212832b20c</ExportTypeId>
        <TemplateDesc>Census Standard Payroll</TemplateDesc>
        <Active>true</Active>
        <DataElements />
    </Template>
    <Template>
        <ExportTemplateId></ExportTemplateId>
        <ExportTypeId>94fb5330-9bd8-4622-8c26-dd212832b20c</ExportTypeId>
        <TemplateDesc>Census Standard Payroll New</TemplateDesc>
        <Active>true</Active>
        <DataElements />
    </Template>
</ArrayOfTemplate>
```

If I create a new `Template` (the last Template entry in the XML example) I want the merge function to auto assign a `newid()`.  How can I do this?  Currently, what I have throws an error of `'Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.'`

Comment: I assume from your code that this is SQL Server? Please edit your question and tag with the correct RDBMS incl. version! You speak about `MERGE` but I cannot see anything to merge... Is it so, that there is data in `#ExportTable` already and you have to merge (update / insert) with data from XML? Is there one XML only or are there many XMLs at once? For sure this can be done better (`FROM OPENXML` is outdated) but I do not fully understand what you need...

Comment: Is this question solved? Do you need further help? Please allow me one hint: If this question is solved, it would be very kind of you, to tick the acceptance check below the (best) answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Since  you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

As told in my comment, `FROM OPENXML` with the related stored procedures to prepare and to remove a document is outdated and should not be used any more (rare exceptions exist). The following shows you, how to use modern XML-methods to read data from an XML.

My magic crystal ball tells me, that you might need something like this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<ArrayOfTemplate xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Template>
        <ExportTemplateId>7f0db0ed-d215-4a25-a38a-0305dddc56b3</ExportTemplateId>
        <ExportTypeId>408b6a56-3b7c-41d8-902a-a20f5b2df170</ExportTypeId>
        <TemplateDesc>Census Standard HR</TemplateDesc>
        <Active>false</Active>
        <DataElements />
    </Template>
    <Template>
        <ExportTemplateId>13691df1-9b4c-4b94-b106-41494fe172aa</ExportTemplateId>
        <ExportTypeId>94fb5330-9bd8-4622-8c26-dd212832b20c</ExportTypeId>
        <TemplateDesc>Census Standard Payroll</TemplateDesc>
        <Active>true</Active>
        <DataElements />
    </Template>
    <Template>
        <ExportTemplateId></ExportTemplateId>
        <ExportTypeId>94fb5330-9bd8-4622-8c26-dd212832b20c</ExportTypeId>
        <TemplateDesc>Census Standard Payroll New</TemplateDesc>
        <Active>true</Active>
        <DataElements />
    </Template>
</ArrayOfTemplate>';
```

The query checks for `/text()`, which is `NULL`, if there is no content, otherwise you'd get an empty string, which is not casteable to a GUID. Knowing this, one can use `ISNULL` and return `NEWID()` in case of a `NULL`-value:

```
SELECT   ISNULL(tmpl.value(N'(ExportTemplateId/text())[1]',N'uniqueidentifier'),NEWID()) AS ExportTemplateId
        ,tmpl.value(N'(ExportTypeId/text())[1]',N'uniqueidentifier') AS ExportTypeId
        ,tmpl.value(N'(TemplateDesc/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS TemplateDesc
        ,tmpl.value(N'(Active/text())[1]',N'bit') AS Active
        --DataElements???
FROM @xml.nodes(N'/ArrayOfTemplate/Template') AS A(tmpl)
```

You might want to read [one of my previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41607880/5089204) about the differences of empty elements and nulls.