# Skip NULL parameters in XML generated from SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml

**What i'm trying to do?:** generate XML from SQL Server 2014

**Problem**: some columns contain NULL - these columns act like attributes in my XML. My Validator does not accept an attribute if its value its empty/null.

**Example**:

```
number      Type        Trat        Frecv 
----------- ----------- ---------- ----------- 
31301879    NULL          1           2           
73229903      2          NULL         2           
73229903      2           1           2
```

**Desired result**

```
<polita number="31301879" Trat="1" Frecv="2"></polita>
<polita number="73229903" Type="2" Frecv="2"></polita>
<polita number="73229903" Type="2" Trat="1" Frecv="2"></polita>
```

!!! Disclaimer: i've read here the method of a variable table, but unfortunately it does not work for me because my columns need to be ATTRIBUTES and i get the **duplicate attribute key**

It looked like this

```
declare @t table
(
 col1,
 col2
)
SELECT 
col1,
'' as col1,
col2,
'' as col2
FROM @t
```

This is my code

```
   WITH    Inreg
              AS ( SELECT DISTINCT
                            *
                   FROM     dbo.C1_UE C1
                            INNER JOIN dbo.C2_UE C2 ON C1.nrp = C2.ContractNumber
                   ORDER BY C1.nrp
                            OFFSET @Page * @PageSize ROWS FETCH NEXT @PageSize
                            ROWS ONLY
                 ),
            TotalP
              AS ( SELECT   COUNT(ContractNumber) AS Nr_pers
                   FROM     dbo.C2_UE
                 ),
            TotalS
              AS ( SELECT   REPLACE(ROUND(SUM(C1.Val_capital)
                                          + SUM(C3.Suma3), 0), '.00', '') AS total
                   FROM     dbo.C1_UE C1
                            LEFT JOIN dbo.C3_UE C3 ON C1.nrp = C3.ContractNumber
                 )
        SELECT  REPLACE(( SELECT    '' as 1
                                    ( SELECT    TotalP.Nr_pers
                                      FROM      TotalP
                                    ) AS '@nr_pers' ,
                                    ( SELECT    TotalS.total
                                      FROM      TotalS
                                    ) AS '@total' ,
                                    ( SELECT *
       --pers
                                                ( SELECT 
                                                         *
                                                  FROM    @C2 C
                                                          INNER JOIN @C1 CC ON CC.nrp = C.ContractNumber

                                                  WHERE   CC.nrp = C1.nrp
                                                FOR
                                                  XML PATH('pers') ,
                                                      TYPE
                                                ) ,
      --acc
                                                ( SELECT *
                                                  FROM    @C3 c
                                                          INNER JOIN @C1 CC ON CC.nrp = c.ContractNumber
                                                  WHERE   CC.nrp = C1.nrp
                                                FOR
                                                  XML PATH('even') ,
                                                      TYPE
                                                )
                                      FROM      @C1 C1 
                                    FOR
                                      XML PATH('poli') ,
                                          TYPE
                                    )
                        FOR
                          XML PATH('decl400')
                        ), '<decl400',
                        '<decl400 xmlns="mfp:aa:dd:d403:dec:v1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="mfp:mfp:aa:dd:d403:dec:v1 file:/C:/Users/a/Desktop/dec.xsd" ');
```

`@C1`, `@C2` and `@C3` are tables that are declared above, also `@pageSize` and `@pageNumber` are fixed values.

Comment: Not clear on the desired results.  Perhaps you could edit your question and add this

Comment: Edited! My Desired Result was in the second `quote`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need - if I got this right - is the standard behaviour:

```
DECLARE @Dummy TABLE(number INT,Type INT,Trat INT,Frecv INT);
INSERT INTO @Dummy VALUES
 (31301879,NULL,1,2)          
,(73229903,2,NULL,2)           
,(73229903,2,1,2);

SELECT number AS [@number]
      ,Type AS [@Type] 
      ,Trat AS [@Trat]
      ,Frecv AS [@Frecv]
FROM @Dummy 
FOR XML PATH('polita')
```

--The result

```
<polita number="31301879" Trat="1" Frecv="2" />
<polita number="73229903" Type="2" Frecv="2" />
<polita number="73229903" Type="2" Trat="1" Frecv="2" />
```

If you need `NULL`s instead of empty strings you can use [`NULLIF()`](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/22/sql-server-explanation-and-comparison-of-nullif-and-isnull/).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41607880/5089204) might help you to understand how XML deals with empty vs. `NULL`

Comment: Hello! It works fine for this. But when i'm trying to add another element inside <polita>, it does not work this way. I need to use TYPE in my FOR -> "FOR XML PATH ('polita'), TYPE

Answer (score 1):

Shnugo's was my first answer (+1), but another alternative if you don't want to specify all the fields is to use XML RAW.  For example

```
Declare @YourTable table (number int,[Type] int,Trat int,Frecv int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
 (31301879, NULL,1   , 2) 
,(73229903, 2   ,NULL, 2) 
,(73229903, 2   ,1   , 2) 

Select * from @YourTable for XML RAW('polita')
```

**Returns**

```
<polita number="31301879" Trat="1" Frecv="2" />
<polita number="73229903" Type="2" Frecv="2" />
<polita number="73229903" Type="2" Trat="1" Frecv="2" />
```

> **EDIT - Thanks Shnugo for the RAW('polita')**

Comment: True, that's the most simple approach!

Comment: @Shnugo I hesitated because you rightfully cautioned me on XML/string manipulation.

Comment: John, I must admit I stopped reading at `FOR XML RAW` Just try `SELECT * FROM @YourTable FOR XML RAW('polita')`. No further action needed... string-concatenation should not be necessary...

Comment: @Shnugo Thanks for the tip!  I had a "brain-fart" on how to change the default.

Comment: That's what friends are for :-)