# XML Value buried inside the node

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I'm ***brand new*** to XML, but not SQL.  I have data structured by our app vendor as follows that I'm trying to load up into a table:

```
<windowsets>
  <windows>
    <question>
      <id Value="81b25d-9385-sk3" />
      <displayname Value="Thermal Break" />
      <answername Value="Yes" />    
    </question>
    <question>
      <id Value="73v32k-2743-fd9" />
      <displayname Value="Panel Profile" />
      <answername Value="Medium Stille" />    
    </question>
  </windows>
</windowsets>
```

Through other posts here I found and got as far as creating:

```
select
    t.x.value('(id [@Value]/text())[1]','varchar(100)') QuestionID,
    t.x.value('(displayname [@Value]/text())[1]','varchar(255)') DisplayName,
    t.x.value('(answername [@Value]/text())[1]','varchar(255)') AnswerName
from @xmlData.nodes('//windowsets/windows/question') as T(X)
```

But it returns nulls for all columns, and I'm guessing that's because it's expecting the format of:

```
<displayname>Panel Profile</displayname>
```

So being the XML novice and all the searching I've done hasn't help me understand how to change the code to pull it when the value is buried in node (not even sure of correct terminology I'm so new).

THANK you for your help!

Comment: btw: This is a good question. +1 from my side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called `attributes`.

To read `attributes` from `xml` try something like this

```
select
    t.x.value('(id/@Value)[1]','varchar(100)') QuestionID,
    t.x.value('(displayname/@Value)[1]','varchar(255)') DisplayName,
    t.x.value('(answername/@Value)[1]','varchar(255)') AnswerName
from @xmlData.nodes('//windowsets/windows/question') as T(X)
```

Comment: All fine, +1 from my side. Just a tiny hint: One should avoid the double slash (*deep search*) if it's not needed. In this case it won't make any difference, but in other cases this might lead to silly errors...

Comment: Thank you so much for the code and the terminology.  This worked like a champ!

Answer (score 1):

This is not an new answer, just some explanation and to much for a comment:

The part within the square brackets is called *predicate* and is kind of a filter. Your expression

```
displayname [@Value]/text())[1]
```

will read the `text()` of `<displayname>` and will check, if the attribute `@Value` exists. Anyway, there is no element's text, so it will return `NULL`.

You must *navigate* down the path like `.../displayname/@Value` if you want to read the attribute's value.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41607880/5089204) shows some examples how XML deals with empty members.